# Do Lightning Platform Starter users have access to write flows and apex code?

Tags: licenses

Do Lightning Platform Starter users have access to write flows and apex code?

According to the [Lightning Platform Starter license documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities_lightning_platform_details.htm&type=0) 
it reads as if this license allows users to execute flows, workflows, process builder flows, but there is no detail about if they have access to create anything in setup or develop apex code.

Would that require a Lightning Platform Starter (Administrator) license?

Comment: nice question. I also am exploring these kind of requirements, and I'm wondering: what exactly is a Lightning Platform Admin License? it is mentioned in the pricing comparison spreadsheet, but I cannot find any information about elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> Do Lightning Platform Starter users have access to write flows and apex code?

Based on documentation, it seems **No** (details below).

---

[Lighting Platform Starter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities_lightning_platform_details.htm&type=0) (or Plus) both contain a Salesforce Platform license:

> Lightning Platform Starter and Lightning Platform Plus both contain a Salesforce Platform license and a Company Communities Permission Set License.

And to be able to write an Apex class, you will need `Author Apex` permission which is [not available for Platform licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_create.htm&type=5).

> For example, don’t create a permission set with no user license and then enable “Author Apex” and assign it to Salesforce Platform users. You can’t assign this permission set to Salesforce Platform users because the Salesforce Platform user license doesn’t allow Apex authoring.

Similarly, to be able to create Workflow rules, the [`Customize Application`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194001&type=1) permission is required, and if you try to create a permission set as in case with `Author Apex`, you will not be able to assign it to any User and that you will receive an error.